# Stored Procedure in mySQL issues

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

For class I am to make a stored procedure named add_parts that will be used to add records to the parts_service table. It has 2 input parameters that match the part_id and parts_qty field/data types from that table. I have to also declare a variable that will hold onto the service_id value from another table services and set it to MAX using a select into. Here is the code I have:

```
/*Set DB context and drop the procedure if it exists (2 lines)*/
USE cf;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_parts;

/*Delimiter statement (1 line)*/
DELIMITER //

/*Create procedure statement & 2 int parameters.*/
CREATE PROCEDURE add_parts (
  IN part_id_param INT,
  IN parts_qty_param INT
)
BEGIN   

/*Declare the internal int variable (1 line)*/
DECLARE service_id_var INT;

/*Declare sql_error variable, Declare continue handler, set sql_error variable (3 lines)*/
DECLARE sql_error TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
SET sql_error = TRUE;

/*Set the internal int variable */
/*From the appropriate table (3 lines)*/
SELECT MAX(service_id) INTO service_id_var FROM service;

START TRANSACTION;

/*Insert into parts_service values statement */
INSERT INTO parts_service VALUES(DEFAULT, part_id, part_qty, service_id_var);

/* If/else conditional; if sql_error variable is false, commit the transaction and select the appropriate message*/
/* else, rollback the transaction and select the appropriate message */
IF sql_error = FALSE THEN 
  COMMIT;
  SELECT 'Record was added!' AS Message;
ELSE 
  ROLLBACK;
  SELECT 'The part id you entered does not exist' AS Message;
END IF;

END//

CALL add_parts(15,7);
```

The CALL in the last line should return "Record was added!" but instead returns "The part id you entered does not exist". How do I tell if I am doing this correctly?

```
CREATE TABLE parts_service (
parts_service_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
part_id int(11) NOT NULL,
service_id int(11) NOT NULL,
parts_qty int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (parts_service_id),
KEY ps_fk_parts (part_id),
KEY ps_fk_service (service_id),
CONSTRAINT ps_fk_parts FOREIGN KEY (part_id) REFERENCES parts (part_id),
CONSTRAINT ps_fk_service FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES service (service_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the error generated by removing the handler. What is the table definition for `parts_service` (`SHOW CREATE TABLE parts_service`)?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `parts_service` (
   `parts_service_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `part_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `parts_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`parts_service_id`),
   KEY `ps_fk_parts` (`part_id`),
   KEY `ps_fk_service` (`service_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `ps_fk_parts` FOREIGN KEY (`part_id`) REFERENCES `parts` (`part_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `ps_fk_service` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `service` (`service_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: No error is generate when removeing the handler

Comment: in a mysql client, can you run this query without error? `INSERT INTO parts_service VALUES (DEFAULT, 15, 7, (SELECT MAX(service_id) FROM service));`?  if not, does the error help uncover the issue?

Comment: Btw with particularly long information requested, its better if you update your question to include this. It is a lot easier to read than in the comments :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, these two are out of order:

```
service_id int(11) NOT NULL,
parts_qty int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

The query (with constraint on the `service` table) must be failing when trying to insert the `parts_qty` to the `service_id`.

Switch your insert to this:

```
INSERT INTO parts_service VALUES(DEFAULT, part_id, service_id_var, part_qty);
```

Alternatively, and this is probably better, you could explicitly set the columns your values are to be placed into:

```
INSERT INTO parts_service 
  (`parts_service_id`, `part_id`, `parts_qty`, `service_id`) 
VALUES
  (DEFAULT, part_id, part_qty, service_id_var);
```